# ngrx reducer is not being called

Tags: ngrx

Hi I am still getting my head around NGRX.

I am trying to store the value of a dropdown in a component into the NGRX store so that I can then use it to set conditional formatting in another componenent when it is loaded.

Here is my form.action.ts

```
import { createAction, props } from '@ngrx/store';

export const formAdditionalFieldsAction = createAction(
  '[Main Form] Toggle Additional Fields Section',
  props<{ showAdditionalFields: false}>()
);
```

My form.reducer.ts

```
import { createReducer, on } from '@ngrx/store';
import { formAdditionalFieldsAction } from './form.action';

export interface AdditionalFieldsState {
  showAdditionalFields: boolean;
}

const initialState: AdditionalFieldsState = {
  showAdditionalFields: false
}

export function mainFormReducer(state: AdditionalFieldsState = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type){
    case '[Main Form] Toggle Additional Fields Section':
      console.log("Current state: " + state.showAdditionalFields);
      return {
        ...state,
        showAdditionalFields: !state.showAdditionalFields
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

I am storing the value when the drop down changes on the settings component here.

```
  selectChanged(value:string):void {
    if(value == "Show"){
      this.ShowAdditionalFieldsControl = true;
    }
    else{
      this.ShowAdditionalFieldsControl = false;
    }
    this.store.dispatch(
      {
        type: '[Main Form] Toggle Additional Fields Section'
      }
    );
  }
```

And my app.module.ts contains StoreModule defined as follows

```
StoreModule.forRoot({showAdditionalFields: mainFormReducer})
```

I can't see any logging in the console when i change the dropdown value.

Comment: Have you also tried `this.store.dispatch(formAdditionalFieldsAction({ showAdditionalFields: booleanVal }))` ?

Comment: make sure selectChanged is invoked, the rest seems fine. A  reproduction would help

Comment: Do you have the Devtools installed to check what the Store looks like and watch for Actions?

Comment: can u provide a simple stackblitz?